# How to show that $\psi$ is onto

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\phi:G\to G_1$ be a group epimorphism. Define

$$\psi:\{H_1:H_1\leq G_1\}\to\{H:H\leq G,\ker \phi\subset H\}:H_1\mapsto \phi^{-1}H_1$$

How to show that $\psi$ is onto without using correspondence theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Choose $H\leq G$ such that $\ker \phi\subset H.$ Then $\phi(H)\leq G_1.$ To show $\phi^{-1}(\phi H)=H.$

$\phi^{-1}(\phi H)\subset H:$ Let $a\in \phi^{-1}(\phi H).$ Then $\phi a\in\phi H\implies\exists~b\in H$ such that $\phi a=\phi b.$ Now $\phi(ab^{-1})=\phi a(\phi b)^{-1}=e_{G_1}\implies ab^{-1}\in\ker\phi\subset H\implies a=ab^{-1}b\in H.$

$H\subset \phi^{-1}(\phi H):$ Let $h\in H.$ Then $\phi(h)\in\phi H\implies h\in\phi^{-1}(\phi H).$